# EJS variable showing as null

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I have a node/express/ejs application and when I go to the page it shows that the variable has `null` value. Here is the route.

```
router.get("/events",  isLoggedIn, function(req,res){
    User.findById(req.params.id).populate("moments").populate("events").exec(function(err,allEvents){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            console.log("Ummm.... the database may be down?.......")
        } else {
            if (allEvents === null){
                res.redirect("/dashboard");
            } else {
            console.log("Below are all the events pulled");
            console.log(allEvents)
            res.render("eventsList", {events: allEvents});
            }
        }
    });
});
```

So events is the variable I am passing into "eventsList". The console.log above the render shows events, and when I make a new event it appends to that list. However everytime it goes to the /dashboard page as if there were null in allEvents.

Here is the code on the client side:

```
 <% events.forEach(function(events){ %>
```

Im gessing it something to do with the if statement, but I cant figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you haven't specified the userId parameter in your route

```
router.get("/events/:userId",  isLoggedIn, function(req,res){
console.log("userId: ", req.params.userId)   
User.findById(req.params.userId).populate("moments").populate("events").exec(function(err,allEvents){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        console.log("Ummm.... the database may be down?.......")
    } else {
        if (allEvents === null){
            res.redirect("/dashboard");
        } else {
        console.log("Below are all the events pulled");
        console.log(allEvents)
        res.render("eventsList", {events: allEvents});
        }
    }
})
});
```

Comment: That did not work, that part of the code had been working previously, no matter where I console.log the   "allEvents" it shows null? is there anything incorrect about that "if" statement?

Comment: there aren't problems with the if else statement; Are you sure that the route it's correctly called?

Comment: please can you post the `console.log(req.params)`

Comment: try with `console.log(JSON.stringify(req.params, null, 2))`

Comment: There are results now, you are correct that there was no id before, I used...
req.user._id to get the id. That worked for the id. Now I have results in my console.log for each event, however there is an error on the page referencing 'events.forEach' is not a function

Comment: the problem isn't the mongoose query; but the user id you use for the job, it's undefined. you must call your endpoint /events/123456 and then in req.params.userId you'll have 123456 - test with the code I've posted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129155/discussion-between-victorious-and-illcrx).